# Sharepoint HTML table with colors

Tags: html, datatable

I'm sure this is super simple, but I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around the logic of it.  I have a SharePoint list of ~100 items, each item has an identifier A-C for example.  I'd like to build a table with the headers A-C and create a row for each of the items in the list and put an X or color the box with that identifies the A-C option.  The number of items is dynamic and can be added to and taken away so the number of rows can't be static.  Basic idea below:

1. A
2. B
3. C
4. C
5. A
6. A
   etc...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all about knowing your identifiers index within the table, so let us suppose we don't know how much identifiers exist and at which index they are placed in, we will retrieve those informations like so: (table first line contains identifiers, every cell contains one identifier.)

```
var t = document.querySelector('#myTable');
var identifiers = Array();
[].forEach.call( t.rows[0].cells, function(el) {
    identifiers.push(el.innerText);
});
```

Before we go further, we need some data:

```
var items = Array({id: 1, identifier: 'A'}, 
    {id: 2, identifier: 'C'}, 
    {id: 3, identifier: 'B'}, 
    {id: 4, identifier: 'C'}, 
    {id: 5, identifier: 'A'}, 
);
```

Therafter, we will insert rows into our HTMLtable, and while adding cells we will have to check if current cell (being added) position is the same as current item's identifier index that we got from table first line:

```
items.forEach(function(item) {
    var row = t.insertRow(-1);
    row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = item.id;
    // We add as many cell as we have identifiers (columns)
    for(var i=1;i<identifiers.length;i++) // First cell stores item ID
        row.insertCell(i).innerHTML = identifiers.indexOf(item.identifier) == i ? 'X' : '';
});
```

Here is a [working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x2wcas8m/) if you want to try this out.

Comment: Cool!! i needed to make a few mods to get it to work with the REST query to the SharePoint list, but this absolutely got me there with a little fiddling.  Thanks so much!!